# How to make unique tokens tokens using java.util.tokenizer in java?

Tags: java, opennlp

i am using my own method to create unique Tokens. Is there any built-in method for this in Apache Open-NLP?

Comment: Add each token to a `java.util.Set`. It will keep only the unique ones.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Java UUID Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html). You can use it to create immutable universally unique identifier (UUID), (e.g., `UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();`).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to use `java.util.Tokenizer` to generate unique tokens.  Its purpose is to split a stream of characters into tokens ... irrespective of uniqueness.

Next, it is not clear what you mean by "unique" or "generate".

- If you want want to generate tokens out of thin air that are guaranteed to be "universally" unique, then use the UUID class.  (But the context implies this isn't what you need.)
- If you simply want tokens that will be unique in the context of the current application execution, create a `long` variable to hold sequence number, increment it each time you want to generate a new token, and concatenate with a string prefix; e.g. "token-1", "token-2" and so on.
- If you want to collect unique words in some text that you are splitting using `Tokenizer`, then just add all of the (`String`) words to a `Set`.  (You probably need to convert them to lowercase first ...)
- If you want the tokens to be canonical (so that `s1.equals(s2) <=> s1 == s2`) then use `String.intern()`.
- If you mean something else ... then you will need to clarify your Question.